# Google drive is not allowing me to access all document and files in iOS

Tags: ios, google-drive-realtime-api

I am making an iphone app and there i need to integrate Google drive api. When i have integrated that into the app then it is only showing the files which i have created from "APP" but i just need all docuemnts and files from google drive to my system. Please let me know. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
i find my answer

GTLQueryDrive *query;

if ([self isRoot])  
{  
    query = [GTLQueryDrive queryForChildrenListWithFolderId:@"root"];  
    query.q = @"'root' in parents and trashed=false";  
}
else
{
    query = [GTLQueryDrive queryForChildrenListWithFolderId:self.metadata.identifier];
    query.q = @"trashed=false";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use this scope kGTLAuthScopeDrive instead of kGTLAuthScopeDriveFile as in Google's sample.